# org html export heading numbers with dot

Tags: org-export

I would like to have heading numbers ended with dot in html:

```
* Heading
* Another heading
```

to be exported as

```
1. Heading
2. Another heading
```

Is there any setting I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve it with a css style appending your dots:

```
span[class^="section-number-"]:after {
    content: '.';
}
```

This can also be embedded in the org document:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>span[class^="section-number-"]:after { content: '.'; }</style>
```